# Using alternate server for specific subdomain - DNS settings

Tags: domain-name-system, smtp, mx-record, cname-record, a-record

I'm trying to set up DNS records for a domain name, such that `mail.domain.com` uses a server that is different from any other request to `*.domain.com`.  As I've been going about trying to figure out how to do this, I realize there's a possibility I'm in over my head.

I've tried a few things that have wound up with a `zone domain.com/IN not loaded due to errors. The zone file at the time looked like this (not hiding info since a simple DNS lookup with reveal everything anyways:

```
$TTL    1800
@       IN  SOA ns1.domain.com. hostmaster.domain.com. (
            1393205447 ; last update: 2014-02-24 01:30:47 UTC
            3600 ; refresh
            900 ; retry
            1209600 ; expire
            1800 ; ttl
            )
             IN      NS      ns1.domain.com.
                     NS      ns2.domain.com.
                     NS      ns3.domain.com.
            MX 10   mail.domain.com.
ns1.domain.com. IN A    198.000.000.125
ns2.domain.com. IN A    141.0.000.89
ns3.domain.com. IN A    198.000.00.114
@   IN A    107.000.00.138
*   CNAME   @
mail.domain.com.    IN A    162.00.000.72
mail    CNAME   mail.domain.com.
```

So, first, is what I'm trying to do an acceptible "good practice/best practice", and second, if it is, how can I set this up so that mail requests go to the IP of the second server, and from there, do I need to set MX records as: `priority mail.domain.com`. (What did I do wrong specifically in regards to redirecting mail.domain.com requests and mx DNS settings to the second servers IP

Note, I am using digitalocean, so I have a DNS entry panel that creates the zone file for me.

Comment: You can't CNAME * to @ -- you're creating a catch-22 situation. `whatever.domain.com` is a CNAME to `domain.com` but you can't have any other RR's in `domain.com`, including NS and MX records.

Comment: Just following up, check RFC1912 for more, section 2.4: http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1912.txt

Comment: I have had * CNAME to @ for months, and have used it succesfully for a subdomain catchall, and using my server to create virtual hosts. This was actually recommended by digitalocean: [how to setup hostname with digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-a-)host-name-with-digitalocean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to specify the FQDN when creating an A record for a host that is on a different network.

### Correction to your zone config:

```
mail IN A 162.00.000.72
@ IN MX 10 mail.domain.com
```

### How this translates to a client perspective is this:

- When a mail server checks for MX routes, it will find `mail.domain.com` as the primary route.
- When the mail server does a lookup on `mail.domain.com` it will return with `162.00.000.72`

### Why you don't need a FQDN in your A record:

```
mail.domain.com. IN A 162.00.000.72
```

This is perfectly fine.

---

```
mail.3rdparty.com. IN A 162.00.000.72
```

This is not valid. **Reason:** You aren't authoritative for `3rdparty.com`

---

```
mail IN A 162.00.000.72
```

This is valid. Reason: anything not ending in a `.` will have the `$ORIGIN` appended to it.
So, `mail` actually means `mail.domain.com`, if you have `$ORIGIN = domain.com`

### Some history:

The `.` actually means the root of all domains.

Take this record for example:

```
mail.domain.com.
```

This is what it means:

- `mail`: a subdomain or "host"
- `domain`: the domain
- `com`: a "top-level" domain (TLD)
- `.`: the root

That's why not appending a `.` to your records will result in accidental records like `mail.domain.com.domain.com.`

But in most modern DNS servers, they assume you mean a dot on the end.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed it up a little. I've just edited it. Let me explain further in my answer, editing now.

Comment: thx, also recognize all my settings as shown above, I already have an a CNAME for `@` which resolves domains to server files from my primary server.

Comment: `@` just means the root of the domain. You can have as many of them as you want. As for interaction with your wildcard, that's a different RR type, so I think it's fine.

Comment: My DNS settings only allow me to enter two fields for MX records: `hostname` and `priority`.

Comment: If that means what I think it does, you would specify `mail.domain.com` with a priority of `1-65535`. Are you saying it doesn't let you specify the record name?

Comment: I guess... for example, to enter a NS record, it give me only one field... the hostname field
and it won't let me enter the range for priority either

Comment: looks like I may have to install a bind server.  There is no bind file in my server, so I'm limited to their DNS service unless I do so.